# Add together two column to make one in select statement

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, select

I am trying to add two columns together and create an alias in a select statement using codeigniter.

I created the SELECT statement in SQL Server Management Studio and it works. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT dbo.Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs + dbo.Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Hrs AS total, dbo.Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Qty, dbo.Job_Operation_Time.Work_Date, dbo.Job_Operation_Time.Employee, dbo.Job_Operation.Job
FROM dbo.Job_Operation_Time 
INNER JOIN dbo.Job_Operation ON dbo.Job_Operation_Time.Job_Operation = dbo.Job_Operation.Job_Operation
WHERE (dbo.Job_Operation_Time.Work_Date = '2019-08-12 00:00:00.000') 
AND (dbo.Job_Operation_Time.Employee = '873') 
AND (dbo.Job_Operation.Job = 'SHOP')
```

Here is the model I created in Codeigniter:

```
$this->db->select('Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs + 
Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Hrs AS total, Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Qty, Job_Operation_Time.Work_Date, Job_Operation_Time.Employee, Job_Operation.Job');
$this->db->join( 'Job_Operation', 'Job_Operation_Time.Job_Operation =     Job_Operation.Job_Operation' );
$this->db->where( 'Job_Operation_Time.Work_Date', $date1 );
$this->db->where( 'Job_Operation_Time.Employee', $employee );
$this->db->where( 'Job_Operation.Job', $job );
$query = $this->db->get( 'Job_Operation_Time' );
return $query->row();
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error Number: 42S22/207

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Act_Setup_Hrs + Job_Operation_Time'.

SELECT "Job_Operation_Time"."Act_Setup_Hrs + Job_Operation_Time"."Act_Run_Hrs" AS "total", "Job_Operation_Time"."Act_Run_Qty", "Job_Operation_Time"."Work_Date", "Job_Operation_Time"."Employee", "Job_Operation"."Job" FROM "Job_Operation_Time" JOIN "Job_Operation" ON "Job_Operation_Time"."Job_Operation" = "Job_Operation"."Job_Operation" WHERE "Job_Operation_Time"."Work_Date" = '2019-08-12 00:00:00.000' AND "Job_Operation_Time"."Employee" = '873' AND "Job_Operation"."Job" = 'SHOP'

Filename: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work,

```
$this->db->select('(Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs + 
Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Hrs) AS total, Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Qty, Job_Operation_Time.Work_Date, Job_Operation_Time.Employee, Job_Operation.Job');
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance